# After using the .load, it loads into bottom of the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

After using the .load, it loads into bottom of the div and I would like to at the top. Im not sure how to do this. It loads what ever position the link is and I would like to load at the top of the div Thanks.

This is my javascript

```
function load(where){
$("#story" ).load("loadFrom.htm"+" #"+where);
}
```

This is my HTML

```
    <div id="story">
        <h2>This is where it all starts...</h2>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
        <a href="loadFrom.htm" id="linkFunction" onclick="load('start');return false;">Push Me!</a>




    </div>
```

My link is at the bottom and the page loads into #story but im at the bottom of the new content and I would like to be at top. Thanks

There is a header to the article and when it loads I would like it to load up there at the top.

Thanks for every ones help. I fixed it and here is the code for someone else.

```
function load(where){
  $("#story" ).load("loadFrom.htm"+" #"+where).scrollTop(0);

}
```

Make sure you pass the parameter through the link on the on click function.

```
 <a href="loadFrom.htm" id="linkFunction" onclick="load('start');return false;">Push   Me!</a>
```

Comment: `load()` will replace all html in `id=story` . Need to explain in more detail what problem is or what you are expecting to happen. Last sentence doesn't make much sense as written

Comment: The links are at the bottom of the div #start and when you click the link it loads the function which loads the div in exactly the same place, at the bottom of the div that loaded. I would like to load at the top instead.

Comment: show the html being loaded... without seeing that it is hard to follow the problem. Not clear at all what you mean by `top` or `bottom`. top of what?

Comment: There is a header to the article and when it loads I would like it to load up there at the top.

Comment: what header , what article? Show html that represents these. We don't have crystal balls to know what you are doing. Still have no idea what `top` means either

Answer (score 0):

Can you place another div into the story and load there?

```
<div id="story">
 <div id='loadHere'></div>
 ...
</div>

$("#loadHere").load("loadFrom.htm"+" #"+where);
```

Comment: I will try to be more specific. If you notice that story has a lot of content and the link is at the bottom. When I click the click the section I am loading and it loads the new section and I am at the bottom where the links are on the div that I just loaded. I am loading another section just like #story and if you notice the h2 at the top, I would like to click the link and be able to scroll to the top of the article and load the page at the same time. Thanks for your help